# Calculating error from error in an aveage value

Tags: error-analysis

Say you want to find the period of a pendulum. You start the pendulum swinging, and you find the time that it takes for the pendulum to complete 10 oscillations, $T'$, to be $25s$. You decide that your observational error in the stopwatch is $0.25s$, and its instrumentation error is $0.01s$, so the most probable error can be given by
$$
MPE = \sqrt{(0.25s)^2 + (0.01s)^2} \approx 0.25s
$$

And so you would have that
$$T' = 25s \pm 0.25s$$

Now say that you want to find the actual period, and its error. The actual period is trivial as its just an average:
$$T = T'/10 = 2.5s$$
But how do you handle the error? Is it $MPE/10 = 0.025s$? Perhaps just $MPE = 0.25$ Or is it found another way?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you'd divide the error in the same way, as your mean value. So the mean error will be 25 ms for the cycle time.

This is the benefit you gain from counting the time of 10 cycles.

The disadvantage of that practice is, that each experiment takes 10 times as long. So no free lunch.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your period of a single swing is given by $T_1 \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$, which is a Gaussian distribution with mean value $\mu_1$ and standard deviation $\sigma_1$. Further suppose that by taking the time for ten periods we obtain as measurement result the sum of ten **independent** single periods, $T_{10} = \sum_{i=1}^{10} T_{1}^{(i)}$. Then, we can show that $T_{10} \sim N(\mu_{10}=10\cdot \mu_1, \sigma_{10} = \sqrt{10} \cdot\sigma_1)$. Therefore, the standard deviation $\sigma_{10}$ is not 10 times larger than $\sigma_1$, but only $\sqrt{10}$ times larger. Using this, you could argue that you have to use $\sigma_1 = \sigma_{10}/\sqrt{10} = 0.25s/\sqrt{10}$.